# Client encoding error while inserting data in database (I'm using Postgre SQL with Codeigniter)

Tags: postgresql, codeigniter

I'm using Postgre SQL with codeigniter application, I have wrote a big code query for signup users. now we got error while signup user.

A Database Error Occurred
Error Number:

ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x96 HINT: This error can also happen if the byte sequence does not match the encoding expected by the server, which is controlled by "client_encoding".

Anybody can help me to fix this out.

Thanks.

Prasanth P

Answer (score 2):

Byte 0x96 is [not valid](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-forms-utf-8.en.php) in UTF-8 encoding. I am not familiar with codeigniter, but probably you need to adjust PostgreSQL client_encoding property to match your input encoding (that is, encoding used within that application) or vice versa.

Check [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/multibyte.html) to obtain list of supported encodings.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I just added encoding format through PHP Code, Now it is worked with me. Because we have no permission to change setting in database.